# Fantasy Lineup Optimizer using PuLP in Python: Optimization Time and Duplicate Lineup Issues

Tags: python, optimization, pulp, linear-optimization

I am working on building a fantasy lineup optimizer using PuLP in Python. I have a dataframe with player information, including fields such as Exposure (minimum percentage of lineups a player should be featured in) and Exclude (to exclude the player from lineups).

```
from pulp import *
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.read_clipboard()
df = df.query("Exclude != 1")
teams = df.Team.unique()
salary = df.Credits.to_list()
projection = df.Projection.to_list()
num_lineups = 20

props = round((df.Exposure*num_lineups),0).to_dict()
props = {x : props[x] for x in props.keys() if props[x] > 0 }
proj = dict()
sal = dict()
for i in range(len(df)):
    for j in range(num_lineups):
        proj[(i,j)] = projection[i]
        sal[(i,j)] = salary[i]        
start=datetime.now()
   
prob = LpProblem("NBA_optimizer", sense = LpMaximize)
choices = LpVariable.dicts("choice",((i,j)  for j in range(num_lineups) for i in range(len(df))), cat = LpBinary)
objective = lpSum([choices[i, j] * proj[i,j] for i, j in choices])
prob += objective
cur_lineup = 0
prev_lineup = 0
for j in range(num_lineups):

    #8-Member Lineup Constraint
    tempExp = pulp.LpAffineExpression(e = [(choices[i,j],1) for i in range(len(df))])
    tempConst = LpConstraint(e = lpSum(tempExp), sense = LpConstraintEQ,
                             rhs = 8)
    prob.addConstraint(tempConst)
    
    #Constraint on Credits - Should not exceed 100
    tempExp = pulp.LpAffineExpression(e = [(choices[i,j],sal[i,j]) for i in range(len(df))])
    tempConst = LpConstraint(e = lpSum(tempExp), sense = LpConstraintLE,
                             rhs = 100)
    prob.addConstraint(tempConst)
    
    #Minimum and Maximum constraint from single team
    team_filter = list(df.Team == teams[0])
    tempExp = pulp.LpAffineExpression(e = [(choices[i,j],team_filter[i]) for i in range(len(df))])
    tempConst = LpConstraint(e = lpSum(tempExp), sense = LpConstraintGE,
                             rhs = 3)
    prob.addConstraint(tempConst)
    
    tempConst = LpConstraint(e = lpSum(tempExp), sense = LpConstraintLE,
                             rhs = 5)
    prob.addConstraint(tempConst)
    
    #Position Constraints - PG Min of 1 and Max of 4
    pos_filter = list(df.Pos == "PG")
    tempExp = pulp.LpAffineExpression(e = [(choices[i,j],pos_filter[i]) for i in range(len(df))])
    tempConst = LpConstraint(e = lpSum(tempExp), sense = LpConstraintGE,
                             rhs = 1)
    prob.addConstraint(tempConst)
    
    tempConst = LpConstraint(e = lpSum(tempExp), sense = LpConstraintLE,
                             rhs = 4)
    prob.addConstraint(tempConst)
    
    #Position Constraints - SG Min of 1 and Max of 4
    pos_filter = list(df.Pos == "SG")
    tempExp = pulp.LpAffineExpression(e = [(choices[i,j],pos_filter[i]) for i in range(len(df))])
    tempConst = LpConstraint(e = lpSum(tempExp), sense = LpConstraintGE,
                             rhs = 1)
    prob.addConstraint(tempConst)
    
    tempConst = LpConstraint(e = lpSum(tempExp), sense = LpConstraintLE,
                             rhs = 4)
    prob.addConstraint(tempConst)
    
    #Position Constraints - SF Min of 1 and Max of 4
    pos_filter = list(df.Pos == "SF")
    tempExp = pulp.LpAffineExpression(e = [(choices[i,j],pos_filter[i]) for i in range(len(df))])
    tempConst = LpConstraint(e = lpSum(tempExp), sense = LpConstraintGE,
                             rhs = 1)
    prob.addConstraint(tempConst)
    
    tempConst = LpConstraint(e = lpSum(tempExp), sense = LpConstraintLE,
                             rhs = 4)
    prob.addConstraint(tempConst)
    
    #Position Constraints - PF Min of 1 and Max of 4
    pos_filter = list(df.Pos == "PF")
    tempExp = pulp.LpAffineExpression(e = [(choices[i,j],pos_filter[i]) for i in range(len(df))])
    tempConst = LpConstraint(e = lpSum(tempExp), sense = LpConstraintGE,
                             rhs = 1)
    prob.addConstraint(tempConst)
    
    tempConst = LpConstraint(e = lpSum(tempExp), sense = LpConstraintLE,
                             rhs = 4)
    prob.addConstraint(tempConst)
    
    #Position Constraint - C Min of 1 and Max of 4
    pos_filter = list(df.Pos == "C")
    tempExp = pulp.LpAffineExpression(e = [(choices[i,j],pos_filter[i]) for i in range(len(df))])
    tempConst = LpConstraint(e = lpSum(tempExp), sense = LpConstraintGE,
                             rhs = 1)
    prob.addConstraint(tempConst)
    
    tempConst = LpConstraint(e = lpSum(tempExp), sense = LpConstraintLE,
                             rhs = 4)
    prob.addConstraint(tempConst)
    
    #Constraint to make sure that no two lineups will have same set of players.
    if j > 0:
        tempExp = pulp.LpAffineExpression(e = [(choices[i,j],proj[i,j]) for i in range(len(df))] + [(choices[i,j-1],-proj[i,j]) for i in range(len(df))])
        tempConst = LpConstraint(e = lpSum(tempExp), sense = LpConstraintGE,
                                 rhs = 0.001)
        prob.addConstraint(tempConst)

            
#Naive Run
print("Runnings Naive Run")
prob.solve(PULP_CBC_CMD(msg=1,timeLimit = 600, threads = 10))
print(prob.status)

for i in props.keys():
    tempExp = pulp.LpAffineExpression(e = [(choices[i,j],1) for j in range(num_lineups)])
    tempConst = LpConstraint(e = lpSum(tempExp), sense = LpConstraintGE, rhs = props[i])  
    prob.addConstraint(tempConst)
print("Running with Player Constraints on Exposure")
prob.solve(PULP_CBC_CMD(msg=1,timeLimit = 600, threads = 10))
print(prob.status)
    


#Statements
def sort_players(x):
    ordered_players = []
    ordered_players = ordered_players+[y for y in x if "PG)" in y]
    ordered_players = ordered_players+[y for y in x if "SG)" in y]
    ordered_players = ordered_players+[y for y in x if "SF)" in y]
    ordered_players = ordered_players+[y for y in x if "PF)" in y]
    ordered_players = ordered_players+[y for y in x if "C)" in y]
    
    return ordered_players

if prob.status == 1:
    print("Found the Optimal Solution")
    print("Time Taken for optimisation : ", datetime.now()-start)


    import numpy as np
    selections = np.zeros((len(df), num_lineups))
    for i in range(len(df)):
        for j in range(num_lineups):
            selections[i,j] = choices[i,j].varValue     
        
    d0 = pd.DataFrame(selections, columns = ["lineup_"+str(i+1) for i in range(num_lineups)]).assign(Player = "("+df.Pos+")-"+df.Name)
    
    lineup_list = []
    for i in range(num_lineups):
        lineup_list.append(sort_players(d0.query(f"lineup_{i+1} == 1").Player.to_list()))
else:
    print("Unable to find the Optimal Solution.. :(")
    print("Time Taken for optimisation : ", datetime.now()-start)

pd.DataFrame(lineup_list).to_clipboard()`
```

I am facing two main issues:

**Optimization Time**: The code is taking a significant amount of time to generate lineups, even for a small number (e.g., 11 lineups). I am looking for suggestions on how to improve the optimization time.

**Duplicate Lineups**: When generating a certain number of lineups (e.g., 11), I observe duplicate lineups among the generated set. I want to ensure that the generated lineups are distinct and do not contain duplicates.

Any suggestions or improvements on these issues would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

[image: Data input]

Comment: Rather than the clipboard, can you please supply enough data for this to be reproducible?

Comment: @Reinderien i have added the snip of the data.Let me know whether its helpful.

Comment: Producing numerous distinct lineups in the course of 1 optimization is going to be a grind, and you would need to do that if you intend to limit the number of lineups any player is in.  Does the model perform well for 1 or 2 lineups?  It isn't clear how you are getting full duplicate lineups (teams) with your constraint in there to difference the scores.  You might QA this constraint a bit by plugging in the values and evaluating.  Lastly...  Your constraint construction style is painful to read.  Why do it this way in `pulp`?  Here are 2 examples of easier-to-read style that deal with teams:

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66326293/python-pulp-positional-constraints-for-a-lineup-generator/66327972#66327972

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74156804/python-pulp-optimization-limiting-total-number-of-one-variable-chosen/74157623#74157623

Comment: @AirSquid Thanks for your comment. I am now able to generate the distinct lineups. Seems like there is some error due to other previous variables. Regarding the Constraints construction. I initially followed the one written in the attached links, For some reason i was getting an error when i tried to google regarding it i came across this form of constraint construction which solved the error so kept it as it is. Can you help me in minimising the optimisation time.? does increasing thread will help? Colab with TPU minimised the time taken but not much.

Comment: Well, there are (obviously) several ways to make constraints, and if this works, it is fine as the slowness is the solve.  The first question is:  so what if it is slow.  Many complex LP’s run for hours.  Let it cook overnight.  Is there some urgency?  You might try to update the CBC solver on your machine.  If I recall, the one that is bundled in `pulp` is fairly outdated and you might bet better performance by installing the newer version and modifying the cbc command in `pulp` to point to it

Comment: If its fine. Can you help me in attaching some useful links for updating the solver. I tried to use some CLP solver but unable to do as well. I mean there is some little proper information on using other solvers with pulp.Regarding the slowness. I play daily fantasy, So in case if there is some information about player illness or starting lineups, it will be difficult to generate lineups.

Comment: A screenshot of your data is not useful. Please use textual or tabular format so that we can copy-and-paste it.